# Map home to django admin

Tags: django, django-views, mod-wsgi

I am using django 2.0.6 with apache2 and mod_wsgi. I would like to map the home url to admin of my application (an internal application which only has the admin and no public interface). The following code in url.py works when I am using django's runserver but does not work when I use apache2 with mod_wsgi

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('', admin.site.urls),
]
```

When using apache2 with mod_wsgi, I get redirected to /cgi-bin/webproc saying "Not Found".

The following works with both django's runserver as well as mod_wsgi

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

My apache config is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        TimeOut 1200

    LogLevel info 

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /media/ /var/www/myapp/media/
        Alias /static /var/www/myapp/myapp/static
        <Directory /var/www/myapp/myapp/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/myapp/media>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/myapp/myapp>
           <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
           </Files>
        </Directory>

         WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-home=/var/www/myapp/env python-path=/var/www/myapp 
         WSGIProcessGroup myapp
         WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Would be grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: Is that the only URL being redirected to `/cgi-bin/webproc`? It sounds like every URL is redirected there and therefore the problem is not specific to the admin panel. If that's the case, and even if not, you should add your Apache configuration to the question.

Comment: please submit your mode_wsgi configuration

Comment: Added my apache config. I don't know why is anything being redirected to /cgi-bin/webproc. (Ignorance...sorry).